# How to handle parameters of pipeline job in DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, dsl

I have a pipeline job which runs a sequence of jobs (Eg; setup >> run test >> clean). I want this sequence to run for 100 different tool with different parameter for each tool. Parameterising is done. So I can pass different parameter.

I am passing one parameter to pipeline as tool list as a string parameter which will have the tools separated with comma (Eg; tool1, tool2, tool3)

Now I want to change the pipeline to run the same sequence(setup >> run test >> clean) in all the tools with tool name passed to one of the job as parameter.

I was thinking I will take this parameter value and spit it with comma and get each tool name and have a for loop around the sequence.

I could get having forloop part and it is working for a multiple run.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    stage('Setup') {
        build job: 'setup', parameters: [string(name: 'tool', value:'<tool>')]
    }
    stage('Build') {
        build 'Build Job'
    }
}
```

But I am not getting how can we split the parameter and give one one to each iteration of forloop in DSL. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the parameter value (*params.tool*)? Or how to split it (*params.tool.split ()*)? or how to do the *for* loop?

Comment: @JoSSI , wanted to know how to split and for loop mainly and split worked like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in jenkins are available under the "param" variable. And you can split a string into an array of strings using the `split ()` function. After that, if you want to loop over all strings, you can use a `for` loop, iterating through the array, something like:

```
def tools = params.tool.split (',') // default separator is blanks
for (String part : tools)
{
    println (part)
}
```

There are different ways to iterate, this seems very intuitive to me. Notice that using the specific separator makes blanks after the comma part of the strings. If needed, you can use the `trim ()` function to remove it.